# clickerhero mercenaries

Tags: code-golf, simulation

## Introduction

I have recently started playing [clickerheroes](http://clickerheroes.com) again. In the recent patch they introduced a new mechanic to mercenaries: their lifetime. Instead of having a random chance at dying now they have a certain lifespan given by a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) of p = 0.2. They can be sent on quests to accumulate a premium currency called rubys. When they die you can revive them paying rubys.

## The challenge

The amount of rewards they bring home are scaling linear with their level, while the revivecost is scaling exponentially, so at a certain level it is better to not revive a mercenary and instead hire a new one.

I wrote some code simulating this challenge but found that it was pretty long and there certainly must be a way to make it shorter.

Your job is to do that and find the level where not reviving makes the ruby return per day reach a maximum.

## More information on mercenaries

- The lifespan of a mercenary is given by a geometric distribution with p = 0.2 in days. Within the day the distribution is linear. Meaning that the chance to die at any given minute is the same as any other minute that day.
- Doing a quest reduces the lifespan by the duration of that quest.
- You can always choose from 4 quests.
- The quest available are random and split in 2 parts.
- The main objective is choosen from a pool of 5 where only 1 is finding rubies so the chance that it is a ruby quest is 1/5.
- The other value is the duration, the possibilities are 5 min, 15 min, 30 min, 1 hour, 2 hours, 4 hours, 8 hours, 1 day and 2 days.
- The reward is given by the base value 0.01112 rubies times the level times the duration/5min (eg 30 min = 6) times a durations factor, since longer quest gives diminishing returns, given in the table below.

  ```
  5 min    1
  15 min   0.8594
  30 min   0.7785
  1 hour   0.624
  2 hours  0.5467
  4 hours  0.4687
  8 hours  0.3903
  1 day    0.3125
  2 days   0.25
  ```
- This means we will always choose the shortest ruby quest and if there isn´t one the shortest other quest.
- The cost to revive a mercenary is `10 + ceiling(1.5^level)`
- After reviving the quest is finished and then a new lifespan is generated
- The level is going up by 1 for every day the mercenary spent questing and it starts at 1.

## Input and Result

This program should require no input. In the case that your language is not able to generate values of a geometric distribution you may take random values from [this](http://pastebin.com/UhLaArkC) list.

The result is a single number that represents at what point a mercenay should be discarded instead of revived.

The precision requirement is not a fixed value like 10%, but instead the accuracy should increase the more repetitions you run, so a perfect value should be theoretically possible given unlimited computation power.

The result of my simulation looks like this:

[image]

I used 50000 mercenarys per revive cap. Below 10000 gives spiky bits due to randomness

Comment: What do you mean by "within the day the distribution is linear'? What about precision issues?

Comment: the chance to die in the first minute of the day is 1/1440 the chance to die in the second is 1/1440 and so on. It should be precise in the sense that running more "lifes" should result in an increase in accuray.